# Decide who is the winner in tic-tac-toe? (more below)

Tags: javascript, project

So this is the "board", which is actually an array:

```
let board = [0,1,2,
             3,4,5,
             6,7,8]
```

As the 2 players click on the actual board, the array changes, so in the end it looks like this:

```
let board = [x,x,o,
             x,o,x,
             o,x,o]
```

And this is the function that decides, if there's a winner:

```
function checkWinner(){
    if (//vertical
        board[0] == board[3] && board[0] == board[6] ||
        board[1] == board[4] && board[1] == board[7] ||
        board[2] == board[5] && board[2] == board[8] ||
        //horizontal
        board[0] == board[1] && board[0] == board[2] ||
        board[3] == board[4] && board[3] == board[5] ||
        board[6] == board[7] && board[6] == board[8] ||
        //diagonal
        board[0] == board[4] && board[0] == board[8] ||
        board[2] == board[4] && board[2] == board[6]
        ){  
            alert('we have a winner!')
        };
}
```

The problem is, this way I don't know who won the round. So I could do this:

```
function checkWinner(){
    if (//vertical
        board[0] == 'x' && board[3] == 'x' && board[6] == 'x' ||
        board[1] == 'x' && board[4] == 'x' && board[7] == 'x' ||
         board[2] == 'x' && board[5] == 'x' && board[8] == 'x' ||
        //horizontal
        //etc.

        ){  
            alert('player1 won this round!')
        };

    else if (//vertical
        board[0] == 'o' && board[3] == 'o' && board[6] == 'o' ||
        board[1] == 'o' && board[4] == 'o' && board[7] == 'o' ||
        board[2] == 'o' && board[5] == 'o' && board[8] == 'o' ||
        // etc.
    ){
            alert('player2 won this round!
    }
}
```

But it looks even worse than the first one.. So Is there a better way to do it? Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you check for a winner after each move, the winner will always be the player who made the last move.

Comment: The tic-tac-toe board is a two-dimensional table with rows and columns. Why do you keep it in a one-dimensional array? There is no benefit of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the board coordinates are 1-dimensional (0-9) rather than 2-dimensional (i.e. a 3-by-3 grid ranging from (0,0) to (2,2)), you can consider this approach:

1. Get the position of each player's pieces
2. Check each player's piece positions against the hard-coded winning combinations. The winning combos are encoded in strings which is less verbose than the conjunctions in the if statement.

```js
function hasWinningCombination(cells) {
  const winningCombinations = [
    "012", "345", "678", "036", "147", "258", "048", "246"
  ];

  return winningCombinations.some(winningCombo =>
    Array.from(winningCombo).every(x => cells.has(Number(x)))
  );
}


function checkWinner(board) {
  const players = {
    x: [],
    o: [],
  };

  board.forEach((cell, i) => {
    if (cell in players) {
      players[cell].push(i);
    }
  });

  for (const [player, cells] of Object.entries(players)) {
    // `cells` guaranteed to be sorted by construction, when calling `board.forEach`
    if (hasWinningCombination(new Set(cells))) {
      return player;
    }
  }

  if (players.x.length + players.o.length === board.length) {
    return "draw";
  }

  return undefined;
}

/////////// usage examples ////////

const board1 = [
  "x", "x", "o",
  "o", "x", "o",
  "o", "o", "x",
];

console.log(checkWinner(board1)); // "x"

const board2 = [
  "x", "x", "o",
  "o", "x", "x",
  "o", "o", "o",
];

console.log(checkWinner(board2)); // "o"

const board3 = [
  "x", "-", "-",
  "o", "x", "-",
  "-", "-", "-",
];

console.log(checkWinner(board3)); // "undefined"

const board4 = [
  "o", "x", "o",
  "o", "x", "o",
  "x", "o", "x",
];

console.log(checkWinner(board4)); // "draw"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const place = document.querySelector('div[place]')
const userSpan = document.querySelectorAll('span')
const numberOfCells = 3
const size = 50
place.style.height = `${numberOfCells * size}px`

const cell = Object.entries({
  height: `${size}px`,
  width: `${size}px`,
  position: 'absolute',
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  border: '1px solid #9e9e9e',
  boxSizing: 'border-box',
  textAlign: 'center',
  lineHeight: `${size}px`,
  fontSize: `${size / 2}px`
}).reduce((e, [s, v]) => (e.style[s] = v, e),
  document.createElement('div'))

const users = [
  new Map(),
  new Map()
]
const color = ['green', 'red', '#c1c1c1']
const badge = ['x', 'o']
let currentUser = 0
let secondUser = 1
userSpan[currentUser].style.backgroundColor = color[currentUser]
const usedCells = []

function replaceUser() {
  [currentUser, secondUser] = [secondUser, currentUser]
  userSpan[currentUser].style.backgroundColor = color[currentUser]
  userSpan[secondUser].style.backgroundColor = ''
}

function createCell(column, row, d1, d2) {
  const d = cell.cloneNode(true)
  d.style.top = `${size * row}px`
  d.style.left = `${size * column}px`
  d._target = [`row${row}`, `column${column}`]
  d1 && d._target.push(d1)
  d2 && d._target.push(d2)
  d._setColor = (u) => d.style.backgroundColor = color[u]
  place.appendChild(d)
}

function createDesk() {
  let row = numberOfCells
  while (row--) {
    let column = numberOfCells
    while (column--) {
      const d1 = !(row % numberOfCells - column) ? 'd1' : false
      const d2 = !((numberOfCells - 1 - column) % numberOfCells - row) ? 'd2' : false
      createCell(column, row, d1, d2)
    }
  }
}

function bingo(u, b) {
  usedCells.forEach((e) => (b.includes(e) || e._setColor(2)))
  const d = document.createElement('div')
  d.textContent = `Bingo user ${++u}`
  document.body.appendChild(d)
}

function gameEvent({ target }) {
  if (target._click || !target._target) {
    return
  }
  target._click = true
  usedCells.push(target)
  const foo = []
  for (let value of target._target) {
    let tb1 = users[currentUser].get(value)
    const tb2 = users[secondUser].get(value)
    if (tb1) {
      tb1.push(target)
    } else {
      tb1 = [target]
      users[currentUser].set(value, tb1)
    }
    target.textContent = badge[currentUser]
    if (tb1.length === numberOfCells) {
      place.removeEventListener('click', gameEvent)
      target._setColor(currentUser)
      bingo(currentUser, tb1)
      return
    }
    if (tb2) {
      foo.push(value)
    } else {
      target._setColor(currentUser)
    }
  }

  for (let value of foo) {
    for (let i = 0; i < usedCells.length; ++i) {
      const ind = usedCells[i]._target.indexOf(value)
      if (ind !== -1) {
        usedCells[i]._target.splice(ind, 1)
      }
      if (!usedCells[i]._target.length) {
        usedCells.splice(i--, 1)[0]._setColor(2)
      }
    }
  }
  replaceUser()
}

// Game
createDesk()
place.addEventListener('click', gameEvent)
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div place></div>
<div><span user1>user1</span> <span user2>user2</span></div>
```

- We collect all possible combinations:
  [image]
- Storing the combination that the player used:
  `users[currentUser].set('column0'|'row1'|..., [cell, ...])`
- If all the cells were collected,
  `'column0':[cell, cell, cell].length === 3`
  ...the user won

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.